# asp.net (social buying) groupon like open source project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, content-management-system

1. Does anybody know a cms(which can be easily extended and modified for social buying support)?
2. Do you know similar open source project?
3. Which cms can you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for something in asp.net MVC. I recommend [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/)

it has some unique features that can not find anywhere else in dotnet opensource projects.